# Replace words in a line using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file like this:

```
"1","www.goole.ca","00:12"
"2","www.yahoo.com","00:16"
"3","www.fb.fb","00:a2"
"4","www.sof.org","00:v7"
```

I want it change place of websites with the next quotation mark string (ex.00:12)
So the file would be like:

```
"1","00:12","www.goole.ca"
"2","00:16","www.yahoo.com"
"3","00:a2","www.fb.fb"
"4","00:v7","www.sof.org"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    "([^"]+)","([^"]+)"$
Replace: "$2","$1"
```

This effectively swaps the second to last doubly quoted term with the last doubly quoted term.

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eupgn2/1).